# Multiline comments in JavaCC

Tags: java, regex, comments, javacc

I'm trying to make a scanner for Javascript with JavaCC. I have several problems, one of which is C-style comments: `/* … */` I need to return the comments as tokens.

Here is one attempt:

```
TOKEN: {<MLCOMMENT:          "/*"        ( ~["*"] | ("*"(~["/"])?) )* "*/">}
TOKEN: {<MLCOMMENT_UNDELIM: ("/*"|"/*/") ( ~["/"] | (~["*"]"/")    )*     >}
```

MLCOMMENT was intended to match closed comments, and MLCOMMENT_UNDELIM open-ended comments. This doesn't work becuase `/*a*/b*/` is a longer match to MLCOMMENT than `/*a*/`.

Here is another attempt at solving this problem:

```
MORE:
{
    "/*" : WithinMLComment
}
< WithinMLComment > TOKEN :
{
    < MLCOMMENT: "*/" > : DEFAULT
}
< WithinMLComment > MORE :
{
    < ~[] >
}
```

This doesn't work either since an open-ended comment would cause EOF in the WithinMLComment state. That's illegal (TokenMgrError is thrown).

**Update:**
I may have found the solution:

```
TOKEN: {<MLCOMMENT:         ("/*"|"/*/") ( ~["/"] | (~["*"]"/") )* "*/">}
TOKEN: {<MLCOMMENT_UNDELIM: ("/*"|"/*/") ( ~["/"] | (~["*"]"/") )*     >}
```

**Update 2:**
It wasn't the solution. `/**//` will be matched by MLCOMMENT_UNDELIM.

Comment: You need to use a JavaScript escape character: "\" before the string.

Comment: What is an "open-ended" comment? The ECMAScript 5.1 standard only mentions two kinds of comments: singleLineComment and multilineComment. If a multlineComment isn't terminated, isn't it an error, and isn't throwing a TokenMgrError a reasonable thing for the lexer to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a multiline comment you can use

```
"/*" (~["*"])* "*" (~["*","/"] (~["*"])* "*" | "*")* "/"
```

For a multiline comment that is missing the final "*/", you can use

```
"/*" ( ~["*"] | ("*")+ ~["*","/"] )* ("*")*
```

Comment: For anyone looking for a way to process comments in a compiler, please use a solution based on lexical states.  The solutions here might be useful for code colouring, but they are not correct with respect to the language definition.